# How to query result count with SAP Cloud SDK java in a batch

Tags: odata, sap-cloud-sdk

I am using the OData v2 Type-safe Client API to get a list of entities with a filter.
The filter list and the entity count is quite long, so I need to use a batch request and paging.
If I do not use batch then the url gets truncated, so that is a must.

I need to know the count of the whole result set.

I tried to use FluentHelperRead<>.count(), but I could not put that into the batch, as it resulted a FluentHelperCount and batch.addReadOperations() does not support that.

I also tried to .withQueryParameter("inlinecount", "allpages") in a batch, but I could not extract the resulting odata.count from the batch result.

Is there any way to do this and get a count of all result entities with batch and filtering and paging?

Comment: It seems using batch with the count request is rather a work around. Could you please share, why the url get truncated? You said the filter list and entity count is long. Could you please share the rough number of chars of the url? What target system do you want to consume? Do you know, how many chars are allowed in the request url?

Comment: Using the batch is best practice for any OData call also for security reasons, so it is not a workaround. The url can get more that 2000 characters in my case, which is the most generic limit for urls. Sometimes the truncation even happens at 1000 characters, I do not know the exact reason, this is just an observation. The backend used is S4 HANA with a Cloud Connector. As I see  SAP Cloud SDK supports all operation in a batch, except the count.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, currently the Typed OData API of the SAP Cloud SDK does not allow to add a count operation to a batch request.

However, it is possible to do this with a workaround:

```java
DefaultBusinessPartnerService service = new DefaultBusinessPartnerService();
ODataRequestCount countRequest = service.getAllBusinessPartner().filter(BusinessPartner.FIRST_NAME.startsWith("A")).count().toRequest();
ODataRequestBatch batchRequest = service.batch().toRequest();
// you can add any other request to the batch body here as well
batchRequest.addRead(countRequest);
Long countOfEntries = batchRequest.execute(client).getResult(countRequest).as(Long.class);
```

Here you are "escaping" from the typed API into the generic OData client.
In there it is possible to pass on the count operation, potentially together with other operations, if you want.

In parallel we will have a deeper look into this and maybe consider this as a feature request for a future version.

Comment: We had a team discussion. Unfortunately, this feature is not planned at least for 2024. Please consider the workaround mentioned by Christoph. Thank you.